# What are 8 sidhdhis and 9 nidhis?

Tags: mantras, siddhi

In many chalisa like Gayatri chalisa and hanuman chalisa I heard this verse.

> Ashta Sidhdhi Nav Nidhi ke data

What are these 8 Sidhdhis and 9 Nidhis?